# Spring Boot 3 with Lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

After I upgraded my project from Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.0 I am getting

> cannot find symbol

compiler errors because of Lombok generated code.

Is there any way to make it work together - Spring Boot 3 and Lombok annotations.

Comment: Did u clean the project? and if you have io.spring.dependency-management you can leave the responsibility to set the correct version of lombok to spring like:

 `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should update to the lattest version of lombok `1.18.24` which runs without problems with `spring-boot-3.0.1`

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>
```

Problem is not occuring actually from `spring-boot` but from `jdk` since `spring-boot-3` requires as minimum `jdk17` and older versions of lombok are not compatible with `jdk17` or newer.

As can be seen from [changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog) `lombok 1.18.22` is the first version compatible with jdk17.

Answer (score 4):

You can leave it to Spring to manage the Lombok version.

Here's an example if you're using **Maven**:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>project-name</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Run `mvn clean install` on your terminal to test it.