# Spring Boot Migration from 2.7 to 3.0.1 Lombok issues `cannot find sybol`

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

this post [Spring Boot 3 Lombock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74952527/spring-boot-3-with-lombok) I already read, it is exactly my issues but the solution does not help me.

The issue occured while migrating from Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.0.1. According to version of lombock both have 1.18.24, which to post above suggests using. See [Spring 2.7.X](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions) and [Spring 3.0.X](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions). (Edit: I got those pages from [Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide))

So I get following error while `mvn clean compile` on my Entities annotated with @Data

```
[ERROR] /home/me/code/connect/services/integrator-service/src/main/java/de/comp/integratorservice/service/data/DataService.java:[113,52] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getKey()
  location: variable d of type de.comp.integratorservice.rest.dto.DataDto
```

All pom.xml are altered to hide company names

Here is my modules pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <parent>
    <groupId>de.comp</groupId>
    <artifactId>pname-services</artifactId>
    <version>1.42-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>integrator-service</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>integrator-service</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- open-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- when switchting to openapi from springfox swagger the compile didnt work any more...  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add application packages -->
    <!-- some other dependencies from our company -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-sqlserver</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.kokuwa.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>helm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Here is the one parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>de.comp</groupId>
    <artifactId>pname</artifactId>
    <version>1.42-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>pname-services</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>


  <properties>
    <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
    <apt-maven-plugin.version>1.1.3</apt-maven-plugin.version>
    <helm-maven-plugin.version>6.6.1</helm-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    ...
    <module>integrator-service</module>
    ...
  </modules>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>io.kokuwa.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>helm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${helm-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <chartDirectory>${project.basedir}</chartDirectory>
            <chartVersion>${project.version}</chartVersion>
            <useLocalHelmBinary>true</useLocalHelmBinary>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>package-helm-chart</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>lint</goal>
                <goal>package</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>copy-dependencies</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

and here is the parent`s parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.comp</groupId>
  <artifactId>pname</artifactId>
  <version>1.42-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <modules>
    <module>pname-commons</module>
  </modules>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <modules>
        <module>pname-external-apis</module>
        <module>pname-apis</module>
        <module>pname-services</module>
        <module>pname-tools</module>
        <module>pname-tests</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>pname-tests</id>
      <modules>
        <module>pname-tests</module>
      </modules>
      <properties>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>


  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <build.tag>latest</build.tag>
    <dockerfile.push.skip>true</dockerfile.push.skip>
    <codechecks.skip>false</codechecks.skip>
    <!-- spring-cloud must fit to the base spring-boot version -->
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>

    <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <openapi-webmvc.version>1.6.14</openapi-webmvc.version>
    <swagger-annotations.version>2.2.7</swagger-annotations.version>
    <logstash-logback-encoder.version>7.2</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
    <com.microsoft.sqlserver.version>11.2.2.jre17</com.microsoft.sqlserver.version>
    <google.guava.version>31.1-jre</google.guava.version>
    <checkstyle-maven-plugin.version>3.2.0</checkstyle-maven-plugin.version>
    <com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.version>10.5.0</com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.version>
    <sca-rules.version>1.3</sca-rules.version>
    <spotbugs-maven-plugin.version>4.7.3.0</spotbugs-maven-plugin.version>
    <com.github.spotbugs.version>4.7.3</com.github.spotbugs.version>
    <de.comp.security-code-generator.version>1.0.8</de.comp.security-code-generator.version>
    <de.comp.kcu.version>1.5.0</de.comp.kcu.version>
    <org.testcontainers.mssqlserver.version>1.17.6</org.testcontainers.mssqlserver.version>
    <com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.iot-service-client.versions>1.34.2</com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.iot-service-client.versions>
    <com.azure.azure-storage-blob.version>12.14.4</com.azure.azure-storage-blob.version>
    <net.javacrumbs.shedlock.shedlock-spring.version>4.43.0</net.javacrumbs.shedlock.shedlock-spring.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.12.2</joda-time.version>
    <querydsl-apt.version>5.0.0</querydsl-apt.version>
    <reproducible-build-maven-plugin.version>0.16</reproducible-build-maven-plugin.version>
    <exec-maven-plugin.version>3.1.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.11.0</commons-io.version>
    <apache.collections.version>4.4</apache.collections.version>
    <org.immutables.value.version>2.9.3</org.immutables.value.version>
    <com.ibm.icu4j.version>72.1</com.ibm.icu4j.version>
    <hamcrest-junit.version>2.0.0.0</hamcrest-junit.version>
    <esper.version>8.8.0</esper.version>
    <esper-runtime.version>8.8.0</esper-runtime.version>
    <esper-common.version>8.8.0</esper-common.version>
    <esper-compiler.version>8.8.0</esper-compiler.version>
    <dockerfile.maven.version>1.4.13</dockerfile.maven.version>
    <apache.commons-text.version>1.10.0</apache.commons-text.version>
    <mockserver.version>5.14.0</mockserver.version>
    <scala.version>2.13.10</scala.version>
  </properties>


  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>pname</id>
      <url>...</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>pname</id>
      <url>...</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    ...
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
      <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
          <!--
           Exluding Sping Data mongodb to avoid CVE-2021-44906 (https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/2021/cve-2021-44906/)
           in versions prior to 3.3.5 and 3.4.1
           -->
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
        <version>${openapi-webmvc.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${com.microsoft.sqlserver.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>de.comp</groupId>
        <artifactId>security-code-generator</artifactId>
        <version>${de.comp.security-code-generator.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>de.comp.kcu</groupId>
        <artifactId>interfaces</artifactId>
        <version>${de.comp.kcu.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <!-- we manage our own version of this dependencies -->
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssqlserver</artifactId>
        <version>${org.testcontainers.mssqlserver.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
        <artifactId>iot-service-client</artifactId>
        <version>${com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.iot-service-client.versions}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        <version>${com.azure.azure-storage-blob.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${com.github.spotbugs.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>${com.ibm.icu4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.collections.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.commons-text.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
        <artifactId>value</artifactId>
        <version>${org.immutables.value.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest-junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.espertech</groupId>
        <artifactId>esper</artifactId>
        <version>${esper.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.espertech</groupId>
        <artifactId>esper-common</artifactId>
        <version>${esper-common.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.espertech</groupId>
        <artifactId>esper-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${esper-compiler.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.espertech</groupId>
        <artifactId>esper-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${esper-runtime.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockserver-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockserver.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockserver-client-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mockserver.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${net.javacrumbs.shedlock.shedlock-spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
        <version>${net.javacrumbs.shedlock.shedlock-spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- start
          Rise Scala version for "CVE-2022-31692" transient dependency of
          spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:3.25
      -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- end
          Rise Scala version for "CVE-2022-31692" transient dependency of
          spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:3.25
      -->
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.github.zlika</groupId>
            <artifactId>reproducible-build-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${reproducible-build-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>strip-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
          <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${dockerfile.maven.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>build-tag-latest</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>tag-version</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>tag</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <tag>${build.tag}</tag>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>push</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            ...
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.github.zlika</groupId>
        <artifactId>reproducible-build-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Took me a long time to find the same issue you are facing. I believe you are facing this issue: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3331

If you are using `@ConstructorBinding` and didn't migrate it to the new way yet, `@ConstructorBinding` should be replaced with `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_={@ConstructorBinding})` or removed altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood something.

[Spring CLI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli.html)

> The Spring Boot CLI is a command line tool that you can use to
> bootstrap a new project from start.spring.io or encode a password.

CLI is not part of `spring-boot-starter`. CLI is only a command line tool used as the [spring io initialized (Web)](https://start.spring.io/) but executes from your local command line instead.

So the [table](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions) that you have referenced in your question means that if you use `Spring CLI` and ask for lombok dependency in a `spring-boot` app of either 2.7 or 3.0.1 the initializer will provide you a newly created project where it would already have declared as dependency the `lombok 1.18.24`.

This would not mean that you don't have to have declared a specific `lombok` dependency in your spring boot project. `spring-boot-starter-parent` would not have one declared for you.

It is just that the CLI would make automatically this declaration in the `pom` of your new project if you choose to use the CLI for project creation.

Comment: Not sure I am incorrect here, as the page https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide references those managed dependencies to check. Within my project I also see `lombok 1.18.24`. As mentioned I do declere `lombok` within pom explicitly but without version, as this is managed by spring-boot-starter

Comment: I added the 3 pom.xml files, as they are all children/parents. Hope this helps. I might forgot to tell, that it worked with `spring-boot-starter-parent` version 2.7.X

Comment: @kism3t I believe it might be related with optional true declaration. Try once to compile it with `<optional>false</optional>`

Comment: unfortunately that did not do it :(

Comment: @kism3t how are you building your project? Through command line from maven? or IDE?

Comment: I do `mvn clean compile` within the modules directory

Comment: @kism3t Normally a multi module project has a root where all modules are linked. Try to go to this directory and execute `mvn clean install` . Then try again inside the specific module the `mvn clean compile`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250832/discussion-between-kism3t-and-panagiotis-bougioukos).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an existing project with lombok dependency, lombok will use javax. However, in 3.0.1 lombok will need to use jakarta instead of javax. Therefore you'll need to purge your existing maven dependency using

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```